# How to optimize mongo inserts?

Tags: mongodb, database

I have multiple clients which inserts records to a table(which have 3 million records) in a central mongo database.
If it's mysql/oracle, i can use sql-loader/stored procedure, to process the inserts in batch.
Is there common method to optimize such senario?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do bulk inserts in MongoDB.  Check out the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-inserts/) for details.

Quoting from the documentation:

> The insert() method, when passed an array of documents, performs a bulk insert, and inserts each document atomically. Bulk inserts can significantly increase performance by amortizing write concern costs.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-inserts/) method of course.

It should be supported in your driver. Just make the first argument an array of documents, as is also shown [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#insert-multiple-documents).

But in the basic form:

```
db.collection.insert([
    { type: "Apple", color: "Red" },
    { type: "Banana", color: "Yellow" },
    { type: "Orange", color: "Orange" },
])
```

Of course you need to set a "sensible" limit on that to keep under the [16MB BSON size limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON%20Document%20Size) on documents. Which is what the **whole** insert statement is.